# SOS error parsing XML android

Tags: android, xml, manifest

I tried to add a permission that i read i had to add to let the program save to a .txt file to the external SD card, and the manifest is giving me an error that I'm not able to solve and it's driving me crazy!! please can i get some help on this? Thank you

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.holamundo"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
 <permission >   </permission>
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.holamundo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".acercade" android:label="Acerca de..."></activity>
    <activity android:name="Mesa1_1"></activity>  //the error icon is showed on this line//
</application>

    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

The permission you're looking for is `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.holamundo"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
```

Comment: yeah but i need to solve the problem that im having on the manifest first, otherwise my app will not run!! do you see anything? I would really appreciate it